# Am I using with + ing correctly in here?

Tags: grammar

Am I using with + ing correctly in here?

> With translation being used as the communication means between/among
>   companies and advertisers, many people could express their opinions on
>   advertisements and billboards in seminars, lectures, papers, and
>   during conferences through the years.

Comment: It's okay is speech but dated in writing. It sets up the passive voice (being used between companies). Better: _Since companies and advertisers use translation to communicate_, many people ...

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  It's an absolute construction, as Ashworth says in his answer.  The "with" could be omitted.

Comment: Is translation no longer being used in the way you describe? If it is, your sentence is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular use of an absolute clause.

This extract from a [Wikipedia article on absolute constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) explains their connection with Latin, explains their contribution to the meaning of the whole sentence, and gives a relevant example:

> Absolute clauses appear in Latin with the modifying participle in the
>   ablative case; for this reason they are referred to as ablative
>   absolutes.
>
> An ablative absolute describes some general circumstance under which
>   the action of a sentence occurs. When translated into English,
>   ablative absolutes are often translated as
>
> "with [noun] [participle]":
>
> *With the city captured, Aeneas fled.*

'The example given inserts a 'being' before 'used', which is better in this case. The Wikipedia example is perfective, whereas 'being used' indicates an ongoing situation.